# CSS float left and right in paragraph with span?

Tags: css, css-float, html

Until now, when I had one line with example

previous --- page width --- next

I used a container div with 2 children, styled float:left & float:right

I am think it could be done from one paragraph line with span's maybe something like:

```
<p><span class="s-left">previous</span><span class="s-right">next</span></p>
```

I tried CSS with:

```
span.s-left { text-align: left; }
span.s-right { text-align: right; }
```

but that doesn't do it..

Answer (score 8):

That's because `span` is by default displayed `inline`, so it has no defined width for the text to be aligned *in* (that's a very loose description, but it'll do for now).

If you want to have right and left aligned text it's not much harder, just:

```
p {
text-align: right;
}
span.s-left {
float: left;
}
```

A demonstration may be found at [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/isine/)